# Pass 'this' object to an angular filter

Tags: angularjs, svg, filter

Assume I have the following svg element

```
<svg>
   <text ng-bind-html="input | filter:arg" >this is a txt<text>
</svg>
```

I want to use the filter to update this `text` element and add more
`<tspan>` to it. To do so, I need to pass `this` to my filter so it appends to the elements using javascript. How do I accomplish this? how do you pass `this element` to an angular filter?

Comment: "this" mean controller scope you mean?

Comment: "this" mean the `<text>` object

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is to use an attribute type [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

In your case you could write something like this

```
<svg>
  <text custom-bind-html="{{input}}" filter="{{args}}">this is a txt<text>
</svg>
```

This way you can access both the `input` and `args` models via the `attrs`, and the element while on the directive.

```
myApp.directive('customBindHtml', function ($sce) {
  'use strict';
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      function applyFilter(input, filter) {
          // modify your input with filter and return it trusted by $sce
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
      }
      var output = applyFilter(attrs.customBindHtml, attrs.filter);
      angular.element(element).html(output);
    }
  };
});
```

`$sce` provider let you secure the content to avoid trust policy errors (enabled by default)

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v1g6xdto/3/)